# ubuntu lunch android-studio crash automatically and system unregister everytime

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, crash

The android-studio version:android-studio-ide-141.2343393-linux,
the system version is ubuntu (x86) 14.04.03 LTS.
When I open android-studio and wait for 5 mins without any operation, the system will unregister always, I's very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating Java to 1.8 and studio to 1.5.

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
-launch Android Studio from terminal
-start last project
-while process of Indexing (progress bur on bottom) Android Studio has crashed without any messages on terminal

Comment: I solved this problem: update Java to 1.8 and studio to 1.5

Comment: Greate, there is it!